# how to prove this

Tags: algorithms

> Prove that $$\sum_{i=1}^ni^p = \Theta(n^{p+1}) $$for $p \ge 1$

Does $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n i^p = n^p\frac{n^p+1}2$ ?

I know that

$$\Theta(g(n))=\{f(n): \text{$\exists c_1,c_2 > 0$ and $n_0$ such that $0\le c_1\cdot g(n)\le f(n)\le c_2\cdot g(n)$ for all $n\ge n_0$} \}$$

but how can I use this definition to prove this relation

any help?

Comment: $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} i^p$ does NOT equal $\frac{n^p (n^p + 1)}{2}$. That would be equal to $\sum_{i = 1}^{n^p} i$.

Answer (score 0):

$$1^p + 2^p + 3^p + \cdots + n^p \leq n^p + \cdots + n^p = n \cdot n^p = n^{p+1}$$
this proves that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^p = O(n^{p+1})$$
to show that it is $\Theta (n^{p+1})$ is similar: call $k$ the integral part of $\frac{n}{2}$, then
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^p = \sum_{i=1}^k i^p+ \sum_{i=k+1}^n i^p \geq \sum_{i=1}^k 0 + \sum_{i=k+1}^n (k+1)^p \geq k \frac{n^p}{2^p} = \Theta \left( n^{p+1} \right)  $$

Comment: not understand please give more details